# How can I show spring batch table's data?

Tags: spring-batch

I'm using `spring-batch` to process something.
(Now I'm just using `tasklet`.)
Now I have to make api that shows result of batch jobs.

result is like below,

```
executor | job name | status | success count | fail count
ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ
joont92  | some_job | FAIL   | 100           | 20
```

As you guys know,
`job name` is `JOB_INSTACE`'s data,
`status` is `JOB_EXECUTION`'s data,
`success count`, `fail count` is `STEP_EXECUTION`'s data.
And `executor` is `JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT`'s data maybe.

Yeah, I need to`join` `spring-batch`'s tables. But I don't know how I have to do.

I've found `JobExplorer`, `JobRepository`.
It seems like to select `spring-batch`'s tables, but I'm not sure this is right way to make result api.

Is there any libraries or way to do this?
Have to use another `spring`'s library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any libraries or way to do this?

`JobExplorer` is the way to go. It is a read-only version of the job repository which is perfectly fine for your use case.

> Have to use another spring's library?

If you don't want to use the `JobExplorer` form Spring Batch, you can query the database with:

- a [`JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html). You can find a getting started guide about it here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/
- or using [Spring Data](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data)

Hope this helps.